# Why can I ssh and return a result faster than Linux can with a bundled command?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh, grep

I'm writing a short bash script that involves logging into roughly 100 nodes and counting the number of processes running in top with my username, and I'm trying to combine the ssh-related processes all into one bundled command:

```
ssh server-1 top -bn1 | grep 'program' | grep -c 'username'
```

When I do this, I notice that it takes roughly 5 seconds to return the process count for a server, which is not long by itself. However, when I want to run this command about 100 times, it would be desirable to speed it up. I can edit my .bash_profile to comment out the following lines:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

From there, I can complete the process of entering the ssh, top/grep/grep, and exit commands by hand in about 3 seconds. Given that the ssh and exit processes only take about 1 second combined (with my .bash_profile commented out) and that the top/grep/grep is nearly instant, it should be significantly faster than 3 seconds if the computer does the commands. However, keeping the .bash_profile commented out does not improve the speed of the bundled ssh command and the bundled command still takes about 5 seconds vs. 3 seconds doing it by hand. Can anyone explain why the bundled command is slower than doing the commands individually by hand, even when the .bash_profile is commented out?

Comment: Study your bash documentation section about which startup scripts  get sourced by default under which circumstances. Generally, profiles get sourced on login shells, and rc's get sourced on non-login shells. I'm guessing since you're invoking a specific command via ssh, it's a non-login shell and thus skipping the profile and sourcing the rc. Also, note that you're only running `top` on the remote machine; those greps are executing on the local machine. (It might not make much performance difference, but I thought I should point it out.)

Comment: "I can edit my `.bash_profile`" – On the server(s), right? not on the client. Please state this explicitly, so we don't have to assume.

Comment: Apologies, I realized my terminology was inaccurate. It would be more accurate to say the processes are jobs on a cluster consisting of a login node and a bunch of compute nodes, and I am logging into a head/login node where I can submit jobs and check on the statuses of these jobs being worked on inside the compute nodes. Thus, the ```.bash_profile``` is initially activated on the head/login node but can be edited before I ssh to a compute node, where the ```.bash_profile``` is read again.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and improve it instead of clarifying in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I can make an educated **guess** - I posit that when you are running a session manually you already have another session logged in, and SSH is making use of  the existing connection in the background.  When you are scripting this, SSH needs to negotiate a whole new session.

There are lots of things you can do to speed up SSH connections - have a read of https://www.tecmint.com/speed-up-ssh-connections-in-linux/ - and especially section 3 which allows you to reuse SSH connections with the following in your ~/.ssh/config file -

```
Host *
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath  ~/.ssh/sockets/%r@%h-%p
ControlPersist 600
```

Alternatively look at "autossh", which worked wonders for me. (From memory - and it was 10 years ago now - I used autossh -M on startup on the monitoring server)

That said, allow me to suggest that if you step back, there may be a better way of doing this - making use of backgrounded processes and performing multiple SSH sections in parellel.  Focussing on this will return a result a lot quicker (albeit even better if combined with the above techniques).

You should be able to background your SSH requests and dump the results to a file/multiple files, then wait for them all to complete, sort and present.

Here is a trivial piece of code to show the concept (Of-course this assumes a trust relationship between the hosts)

```
  #!/bin/bash

  TEMPFILE=/dev/shm/temp.$$

  for each in host1.name host2.name host3.name host4.name
  do
        ssh $each "ssh command(s) here" >> $TEMPFILE  &
  done
  wait
 
  cat $TEMPFILE
  rm $TEMPFILE
```

The magic bits here are -

- The & at the end of the SSH line backgrounds the request.
- The wait command waits for all the backgrounded processes to exit.